# Single View model for activity and multi fragments in android app

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments

I have an activity of TravelActivity
and some fragments
the ui hierarchy is:

-travel

--travelActivity (activity)

--addTravel (fragment)

--list of travels (fragment)

--archive travels (fragment)

etc'

I want that if the `add travel fragment` add single travel item then the `list fragment` updated

my questions:

1. What the Best Practice for this, I don't know if for each fragment I create specific view model or use same view model for all the fragments and activities
2. If same view model how can I share single viewmodel with multi fragments

Thanks!

This is my ViewModel:

```
public class TravelViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    ITravelRepository repository;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth  = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    public User getCurrentUser() {
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        .....

    }
    private MutableLiveData<List<Travel>> mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public TravelViewModel(Application p) {
        super(p);
        repository = TravelRepository.getInstance();
        ITravelRepository.NotifyToTravelListListener notifyToTravelListListener = new ITravelRepository.NotifyToTravelListListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTravelsChanged() {
                List<Travel> travelList = repository.getAllTravels();
                mutableLiveData.setValue(travelList);
            }
        };
        repository.setNotifyToTravelListListener(notifyToTravelListListener);
    }
    void addTravel(Travel travel)
    {
        repository.addTravel(travel);
    }
    public void updateTravel(Travel travel)
    {
        repository.updateTravel(travel);
    }
    MutableLiveData<List<Travel>> getAllTravels()
    {
        return mutableLiveData;
    }
    MutableLiveData<Boolean> getIsSuccess()
    {
       return repository.getIsSuccess();
    }


}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: My mistake I put the implementation in the wrong place, currently working, thanks